# Are there any SPDY/WebSockets Libraries for .NET available?

Tags: .net, windows-8, microsoft-metro, websocket, spdy

I want to develop a Windows 8 Metro style app and wonder if there are any libraries for SPDY or Websockets protocols available? They should be free too :-)

Comment: I found a link to a C# SPDY implementation here - https://kinderbasar-luhe.de:8543/svn/PreisserNormaleProjekte/SpdyConnector/.Net/SPDY-Redirector/SPDY_Redirector/ I haven't used it/and have no idea what the license to it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### WebSocket

A list of WebSocket clients (including .NET ones) can be found here:
http://www.leggetter.co.uk/real-time-web-technologies-guide#websocket-client-libraries

.NET 4.5 has a WebSocket namespace and a number of classes:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh159285.aspx

There also appears to be a Windows Store apps specific class (MessageWebSocket):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.sockets.messagewebsocket.aspx

You can see an example of this being used [here](https://github.com/digitalcreations/Pusher.NET/blob/master/Pusher.Connections.WindowsStore/WebSocket.cs#L12)

Comment: Sorry, I had a brief search for SPDY .NET libraries but didn't come up with anything. May be worth updating the quesiton to only address one thing - WebSocket libraries - and open a new one for the SPDY question. Probably worth clarifying if you are looking for client libraries (which I assumed you were) or if you want both client and server ones. @igrigorik is the go-to guy for SPDY related IMHO things so I'd recommend you ping him.